# My SQL Replication to an online database server

Tags: mysql, replication

I have two MySQL Databases:

1. On a local machine (connected to internet via a static IP)
2. My SQL database on my webserver (JustHost, which I can access remotely)

I want a replicate my local database to the online one. AFAIK I cannot modify the configuration files of the database. So is there any way to set up replication between these two, or is there any way to accomplish my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Tungsten](http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/) for this, but only master->slave replication. Set up your local machine as a master, and connect tungsten to it. It will then run the statements as a normal client on the remote machine.